# How to create SPFX webparts? Steps till the deployment and debugging

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to know the basics and creating webpart using SPFx(SharePoit framework) i need the completed steps till the deployment and debugging in sharePoint online.

Comment: Below is the very basic video link. It can clear all concept from basics.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the very basic video link. It can clear all concept from basics.

First Set up environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Install Node Js, NPM, Yoman Template, VS Code. Then build your first webpart. VS code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

To debug you can check below article.
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/debug-in-vscode.md

Debugging it just a matter of change the url in the manifest file and press f5.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your input let me try this..If i have any questions will reach you..

Answer (score 1):

Please check the step by step demo from Microsoft Official about SPFX Development, it will contain basic demo and deploy, debug steps:

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)